# ms access date default value and how to unchecked option button once refresh form or clicked save button

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I have a problem here regarding **MS ACCESS date** and **option button**.

I'm creating a form and put a time stamp. Time stamp only can be display if user click the option button.

Here is my source code:

```
Private Sub Option76_Click()

Me.Date_Stamp.DefaultValue = False

If Me.Option76.Value = True Then

    Me.Date_Stamp.Visible = True
    Me.Date_Stamp.Value = Now()
    Me.Date_Stamp.Format = "dd / mm / yyyy"
Else
    Me.Date_Stamp.Visible = False
    Me.Date_Stamp.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

It works well and displaying current date. But once I click **save button** or **refresh**, the date will change to **30 / 12 / 1899** and the option button still on checked. 
How to unchecked the option button and set default value as empty every time user refresh form or click save button?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Do you want it to reset every time you refresh or save the page?

Comment: Hi @BasDeBeer .Yes, I want the form to be reset without any data left once user click refresh form or save button.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that you set the default value to 0 which is the numeric value of 1899-12-30.

Several other things to look for:

```
Private Sub Option76_Click()

    ' Doesn't make much sense here. 
    ' Should be moved to either OnLoad or AfterUpdate of the form.
    ' DefaultValue is a string.
    Me!Date_Stamp.DefaultValue = ""            ' For no value.
                                               ' For today's date:
    Me!Date_Stamp.DefaultValue = "#" & Format(Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
    Me!Date_Stamp.DefaultValue = "#3/4/2015#"  ' For 2015-03-04.

    ' Rename Option76 to something meaningful.
    If Me!Option76.Value = True Then
        Me!Date_Stamp.Visible = True
        Me!Date_Stamp.Value = Date
        ' Not needed. Set the Format property of the textbox.
        ' Me.Date_Stamp.Format = "dd / mm / yyyy"
    Else
        Me!Date_Stamp.Visible = False
        Me!Date_Stamp.Value = Null
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav ! I've tried your codes and there's so many error. But once I changed **Me!** to **Me.** , it's totally work! Lots of thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can put do this in the ".BeforeSave" and ".AfterRefresh" events.

```
Me.Date_Stamp.Visible = False
Me.Option76.Value = False
Me.Date_Stamp.Value = Format(Null, "Standard")
```

Comment: sorry but I couldn't find ".BeforeSave" nor ".AfterRefresh" event in MS Access. Maybe it's MS Excel event or maybe I'm the one tht couldn't find it. Sorry I am a beginner for ms access.

Answer (score 0):

What about saving your record through VBA, reset the Option76 and then recall the procedure again to reinitialize your form:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    DoCmd.Save
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me.Option76.Value = False
    Call Option76_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried out your codes and it's perfectly works! my option button finally unchecked once user clicked save button. Thanks a lot! But when I refresh the form, the date sadly still change to 30/12/1899. Really hope to get your help :)

Comment: How do you refresh your form, just pressing F5 or through a button?

Comment: I'm pressing F5 button. btw I've got the solution by changing **Date_Stamp.DefaultValue** and **Date_Stamp.Value** from **False** to **" "** . Thanks for your help!